# Block quote border/padding/color issue

Tags: html, css

I am making a personal page using bootstrap and want to use a blockquote element, however on just the left hand side I get a white line that will not go away even when I wrap the element in multiple divs and try to overwrite whatever border or margin issue that is preventing it from having the same background color.  Could someone help me figure out what to do?

HTML

```
<div class="top-info">  
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4"><img src="http://www.psdgraphics.com/file/male-silhouette.jpg" width="300" height="250" ></div>
                <div class="col-md-8">

                <blockquote>    
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla gravida velit sit amet dolor iaculis, nec semper felis dictum. Vestibulum commodo magna sed enim elementum, in euismod purus molestie. Nulla et nisl sit amet ipsum eleifend facilisis et a nisi. Cras lectus arcu, efficitur ac dictum vel, porttitor lobortis purus. Phasellus tincidunt velit eget ipsum aliquam, non egestas tellus consequat. Curabitur ullamcorper, massa et consequat mollis, metus neque rhoncus felis, eget condimentum lacus elit ac lacus. Pellentesque volutpat euismod neque, nec semper nisl interdum ac. </p>
                    </blockquote>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.top-info{
    background-color:#848484;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
blockquote{
    background-color:#848484;
    padding:none;
    margin:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap by default use `border-left` in the `blockquote` element. Setting to none will remove the border.

**CSS**

```
blockquote {
    border-left: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap uses `border-left` property to set this "white line" on the left. So all you need to do is to reset it with your custom CSS styles, for example like this:

```
blockquote {
    border-left: 0;
}
```